# A/AAAA returns no answer when SRV record exists for hostname

Tags: domain-name-system, a-record, dig, srv-record

I have encountered a problem where DNS `A` queries that would normally be answered by `*.fqdn` started returning `NO ANSWER` after I added `SRV` record for service residing on said hostname.

```
Example:

*.jozefmutis.com.                               3600  A    78.46.73.72
_factorio._udp.factorio-modded.jozefmutis.com.  3600  SRV  1  1  34199 primary.jozefmutis.com
```

Now `dig factorio-modded.jozefmutis.com IN A` no longer returns answer `factorio-modded.jozefmutis.com. 3600 IN A 78.46.73.72` and instead returns

```
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 53115
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
```

, whereas `dig factorio-modded2.jozef mutis.com IN A` (non existant in SRV and A) properly returns `factorio-modded2.jozefmutis.com. 3600 IN A 78.46.73.72`, being covered by wildcard A record..

Is there any reason why A fails when SRV exists for hostname? I couldn't find anything mentioned in RFC, but common sense tells me that the service identifier in SRV record should prevent sinkhole even for udp lookups. Adding dedicated A record `factorio-modded.jozefmutis.com.  3600  A  78.46.73.72` results in proper IP4 returned for A lookups, although setting up A record for each SRV seems dumb, when * should cover that.

Answer (score 4):

A wildcard only matches if there is nothing more specific.

`_factorio._udp.factorio-modded.jozefmutis.com.` name implictely defines `factorio-modded.jozefmutis.com.` which becomes an ENT or Empty Non Terminal that is a node existing in the tree (by virtue of other nodes below existing) but without content at this node. Which is exactly why you get `NOERROR` and no content: it is not an error, the name exists, but it has no `A` record. If fact it has no records of any type, because nothing is defined at that node level, only "below".

This name (`factorio-modded.jozefmutis.com.`) is more specific than the wildcard of `*.jozefmutis.com.` so any request for records at `factorio-modded.jozefmutis.com.` will be replied by what is defined on this name (nothing, because it is an ENT), and NOT anymore by the wildcard that is not taken into account here because less specific.

Look at the Wikipedia page it has exactly your use case.
At https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record a zone has:

```
*.example.               3600     TXT   "this is a wildcard"
*.example.               3600     MX    10 host1.example.
_ssh._tcp.host1.example.  3600     SRV   <SRV RDATA>
_ssh._tcp.host2.example.  3600     SRV   <SRV RDATA>
```

and the text says, if you query for `host1.example` `MX` record thinking that the wildcard will kick in but it does not:

> No wildcard will match because host1.example. exists. Instead you will
> get an answer of "no error, but no data". The wildcard MX record does
> not provide MX records for domains that otherwise exist.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, it has brought some clarity to RFC 1034, RFC 1912 and RFC 4592. Are you aware if the specification allows data sent, even is node exists in tree with different type? Does the client have any way of knowing that NOERROR should be sent instead of actual response? Does any server implementation allows this (bind etc..)? I've seen people skirt around the problem with external DNS and ingress monitoring (https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/issues/806), but surely BIND9 or other mainstream services should be able to mitigate this behaviour?

Comment: I am not sure to understand your questions. What you observe is exactly what DNS specifications require, so everything is normal (`NOERROR` is the real return code here, `NO ANSWER` or more precisely `NODATA` just means `NOERROR` + no data in the Answer section), and for good reasons even if it may not be clear. If you want an `A` record, just add `factorio-modded2.jozefmutis.com. 3600 A 78.46.73.72` in addition to what you have already, and it will work as you expect.

Comment: "but surely BIND9 or other mainstream services should be able to mitigate this behaviour?" What behaviour? There is nothing to "mitigate", the answer you see conform to the DNS specifications. Wildcards may be confusing so the best advice is : DO NOT use them. Pre-generate your zonefiles with all data you need, and hence no wildcard will be needed. This will save you various headaches.

Comment: I'm talking about whether returning arbitrary data instead of NOERROR, albeit non-conforming to specification, breaks any behaviour. It shouldn't be hard to maintain separate node tree for each record-type.

Comment: "I'm talking about whether returning arbitrary data".  Yes, just define record `factorio-modded.jozefmutis.com.` record explicitly in your zonefile with whatever data you want, and it will be served.

Comment: @jackar I think what you are looking for may be some form of metalanguage/templating system that generates zone data for you or even a view of zone data generated dynamically on demand, which would certainly be possible (and would be in line with what Patrick has been saying). Trying to have DNS wildcards (part of the actual visible zone data) behave differently than the spec mandates is not how you do it, that will not interoperate with other things (not for zone transfers, not for DNSSEC, maybe other things as well).